# Darboux property for function that $lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{g(x+1/3)+g(x+2/3)}{x} = 1$

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

Let $g$ be a continuous function for $x\in[0,1]$ and it has this property that
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{g(x+1/3)+g(x+2/3)}{x} = 1
$$
How to prove that there exists $t\in[0,1]$ such as $g(t)=0$.

**My approach:**

As $g$ is continuous function we can write
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{g(x+1/3)+g(x+2/3)}{x} = 1 = \frac{g(\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}(x+1/3))+g(\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}(x+2/3))}{\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x}
$$
so 
$$
0=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x=g(\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}(x+1/3))+g(\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}(x+2/3)) = g(1/3)+g(2/3)
$$
so $g(1/3)=-g(2/3)$
And now using the Darboux property for continuous function we can state that there exists at least on $t\in[0,1]$ that $g(t)=0$.
I'm not sure of the corectness of the first step.

Answer (score 1):

What is

$\frac{g(\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}(x+1/3))+g(\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}(x+2/3))}{\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x}$ ???? We have $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x=0$ !!!

Since $g$ is continuous, we get $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}(g(x+1/3)+g(x+2/3))=g(1/3)+g(2/3)$.

If  $g(1/3)+g(2/3) \ne 0 $, we would get $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{g(x+1/3)+g(x+2/3)}{x} \in \{ - \infty, \infty\}$, a contradiction, hence $g(1/3)+g(2/3) = 0 $.

Now suppose that $g(t)>0 $ for all $t \in [0,1]$, hence $g(1/3)+g(2/3)> 0 $, which is impoosible.

Now suppose that $g(t)<0 $ for all $t \in [0,1]$, hence $g(1/3)+g(2/3)< 0 $, which is impoosible.

Conclusion: there is $t \in [0,1]$ such that $g(t)=0$.

Comment: Why the downvote ?